# Object to time conversion in pandas derived column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, types

HI need help with datetime,

I have extracted minutes second value in the form of mm:ss eg(23:50)
but after that now I need to convert the same in '%H:%M:%S' format but it is giving error as it is in type dtype('o'), used below code but it is giving error, what to do

```
df_raw['Time-only'] = pd.to_datetime(df_raw['time2'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```

Comment: please show a few rows of your data, print `df.head(5).to_dict()` paste the output in your question exactly as you see it. Also, if possible, show what you would expect. saves guess work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need convert values to timedeltas for next vectorized processing like subtract or sum:

```
df_raw = pd.DataFrame({'time2':['23:50','15:23']})

df_raw['Time-only'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df_raw['time2'])
print (df_raw)
   time2       Time-only
0  23:50 0 days 00:23:50
1  15:23 0 days 00:15:23
```

If convert to times then is not possible use vectorized operations, because get object `python time`.

Comment: @Manakin - hmm, convert to timedeltas?

Comment: oh you are right, I I thought your call was to to_datetime, my bad

Answer (score 0):

First, to_datetime is used to convert a given string format into DateTime. For example, if I had a string '2018-04-10 12:37:51.252'

```
df_raw['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df_raw['time2'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

doing the above will simply change the data types. You can verify them by doing

```
df_raw.dtypes
```

Now, to answer your question I believe you are trying to convert timestamp mm:ss to hh:mm:ss? If not, can you be more specific?

```
df_raw['Time-only'] = list(df_raw['time2'].map(lambda f: datetime.strftime(f, "%H:%M:%S")))
```

This piece of code will change the format of your timestamp to 12:37:51.

Comment: used the solution but it is throwing error as:TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

Comment: Because the type of 'time2' is str. First, convert time2 to timestamp by doing
df_raw['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df_raw['time2'], format='<your-format-here>')

Comment: that is only my issue that I am unable to conert it to datetime

Comment: Can you paste the exact values that you are trying to convert? or any row of your data frame.